# Fix error ''Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead'' on a scaler

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, autoencoder

I am testing an .ipynb file with code to perform data augmentation using autoencoders. You can find the file in the following link: [Autoencoder Data Augmentation Example](https://github.com/lschmiddey/fastpages_/blob/master/_notebooks/2021-03-14-tabular-data-variational-autoencoder.ipynb)

Dataset used: [wine.csv](https://gist.github.com/tijptjik/9408623)

The first error I encountered was a variable that did not exist and was renamed:

```
# D_in = data_set.x.shape[1]
D_in = traindata_set.x.shape[1]
H = 50
H2 = 12
model = Autoencoder(D_in, H, H2).to(device)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
```

Later, I get another error derived from the following code:

```
scaler = trainloader.dataset.standardizer
recon_row = scaler.inverse_transform(recon_batch[0].cpu().numpy())
real_row = scaler.inverse_transform(testloader.dataset.x[0].cpu().numpy())
```

I get the following error that I can't solve:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[-1.1050762   0.59396696 -0.40257156  0.5084665  -0.3387986   0.5908352
  0.6442218   0.7660801  -0.36749032  0.2818777  -0.06692128  0.49236417
  0.7825899   0.8493577 ].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) 
if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

I hope you can help me to detect it.

Comment: Are you looking for a different answer to @edg one below?  That seems to be the right answer to me - it worked when I tried it and makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like `inverse_transform` is expecting a matrix. In your code you are passing a single sample (row), so that doesn't work.
If you follow the error message tip and reshape your input the cell runs.

```python
recon_row = scaler.inverse_transform(recon_batch[0].cpu().numpy().reshape(1, -1))
real_row = scaler.inverse_transform(testloader.dataset.x[0].cpu().numpy().reshape(1, -1))
```

Now that you have 2 matrix of shape `(1,14)` you also need to change the next cell in order to use only the first (and only) sample in the matrix :

```python
df = pd.DataFrame(np.stack((recon_row[0], real_row[0])), columns = cols)
```